# Integration of paypal in Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, api, paypal

I want to integrate paypal checkout in my website. I have added this line in composer and updated composer

```
"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
```

I have also added AddMoneyController and needed routes in route.php files.
But I have this error in the controller and can't figure out what is the point.

> Class 'PayPal\Rest\ApiContext' not found

The first part of my controller look like this:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use URL;
use Session;
use Redirect;
use Input;

/** All Paypal Details class **/

use PayPal\Rest\ApiContext;
use PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential;
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\ExecutePayment;
use PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;
class AddMoneyController extends HomeController
{
    private $_api_context;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        /** setup PayPal api context **/
        $paypal_conf = \Config::get('paypal');
        $this->_api_context = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($paypal_conf['client_id'],
                                                $paypal_conf['secret']));
        $this->_api_context->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    }
    /**
     * Show the application paywith paypalpage.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

Have you any thoughts what is the point? Thanks.

Comment: Have you added the provider and aliases in `config\app.php`?

Comment: No, I haven't add the provider and alias, cause I use this tutorial, adn ther ewas not mention to add provider and alias. http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-with-laravel54example.html

Comment: I also tried using https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal this tutorial, but again no luck. I am trying update composer like this: to composer require netshell/paypal dev-master, but in command line it saying: intallation failed, could not scan for classes inside "tests/TestCase.php which does not appear to be a file nor a folder. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I found was the main issue, composer was not updated as it should. That's why I received these errors.

Comment: For future reference you may want to take a look at our [PayPal PHP class library](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/).  It's a lot easier to use than PayPal's SDKs and works very well with Composer.